# converting pandas column to np 2d array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot, dataframe

I am adapting a pandas plotting example for my own data. I have a question on converting a pandas dataframe column to the correct shape (1 , 10). More specifically. the correct format is achieved with this code

```
z = np.random.rand(1, 10)
```

which produces this

```
array([[ 0.45671971,  0.21101451,  0.08022069,  0.80602989,  0.92816774,
     0.03677719,  0.97893078,  0.97003696,  0.23232276,  0.65328171]])
```

My dataframe column is created like this

```
y = df['col_name'].as_matrix()
```

which is creating this

```
array([218584205,  55738338,  52152386,  37920152,  35472238,  32611026,
    30268255,  26709195,  25979749,  24804423], dtype=int64)
```

notice the extra bracket. So the shape is (10, 1). What is the correct method for converting the column to the correct form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y = df['col_name'].as_matrix().reshape(1, len(df['col_name']))
```

Yields:

```
array([[218584205,  55738338,  52152386,  37920152,  35472238,  32611026,
     30268255,  26709195,  25979749,  24804423]])
```

Comment: Correct method so I upvoted it. It did need a small tweak of                                               y = df['col_name'].as_matrix().reshape(1, len(df['col_name'])). +1 thanks